# Illegal invocation Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

Fixed the problem by putting the array "checkbox_values" into the request. Tnx for your time and help guys!

```
        var checkbox_values = new Array();
        var subscriber_id = jQuery('#subscriber_id').prop('value');
        var subscriber_name = jQuery('#subscriber_name').val();
        var subscriber_mail = jQuery('#subscriber_mail').val();
        jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            checkbox_values.push(jQuery(this).val()) 
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: nieuwsbrief.updatesubscriber,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { subscriber_id: subscriber_id, 
                    subscriber_name: subscriber_name, 
                    subscriber_mail: subscriber_mail, 
                    checkbox_values: checkbox_values.join('|')
                  },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Use `.map().get()` instead of `.each()` and the separate array for `checkbox_values`.

Comment: have checked by keeping logs at destination url whether requesting is getting or not ?

Comment: It gets subscriber_id, name and mail. Only sub_cat doesn't works and i keep getting an illegal invocation error.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error before.
The fix for me was to remove the jQuery objects from the data objects being sent.

```
data: { subscriber_id: jQuery('#subscriber_id').prop('value'), 
                subscriber_name: jQuery('#subscriber_name').val(), 
                subscriber_mail: jQuery('#subscriber_mail').val(), 
                sub_cat: jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                             checkbox_values.push(jQuery(this).val()) 
                         })
              },
```

Something like...

```
 // create the strings first
 var subscriber_id = jQuery('#subscriber_id').prop('value');
 var subscriber_name = jQuery('#subscriber_name').val();

 jQuery.ajax(
 //...
 data: { subscriber_id: subscriber_id, 
         subscriber_name: subscriber_name, 
         //...
 },
```

Comment: Have you done the same thing for `sub_cat`? i.e create the object before the ajax call and adding that object to the `data` object?

Comment: Fixed it, see my question :)

Comment: @user2237168 that's what I meant in my comment/answer (create the objects first). Glad to hear it's working.